# Elasticsearch post_filter

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

Is there any way to apply multiple conditions to the post_filter in elasticsearch?

```js
GET /job/_search
{
  "post_filter":
      {
        "terms": {
          "expertise_level": [
            "medium",
            "high"
          ]
        }
      },
    "aggs": {
      "expertise_level": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "expertise_level",
          "size": 10
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This will work. But I want to add multiple filters to the query. How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bool` clause:

```
{
"post_filter": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
          //Add  Filter 1
        },
        {
          //Add  Filter 2
        },
        {
           //Add  Filter 3
        }
     ]
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "terms": {
          "FIELD": [
            "VALUE1",
            "VALUE2"
          ]
        }},
        {
          "terms": {
            "FIELD": [
              "VALUE1",
              "VALUE2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```